# HTML5 Animation problems with Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, drawing

I'm trying to make some kind of lightning radar with HTML 5. Problem is that the code works *perfectly* with Firefox but with Chrome only one of the animations works. I didn't even try with IE...

I checked the code with Chrome's console and console.log() function and everything was fine. All values was OK and all for loops work, but still no drawing. There was also no errors neither on Firefox's or Chrome's console.

Can you help me on this?

I wrote comments next to those three functions so it's easier to find out what I'm talking about:

```
function newLightningAnim() {
    var radius = 200;
    var time = (new Date()).getTime() - lightningStart;
    var newRadius = radius - time / 7;
    var time2 = (new Date()).getTime() - selectionStart;
    var mouseRadius = time2 / 5;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if(lightningImg.src){ctx.drawImage(lightningImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);}

    if(lightnings.length > 0) { // Works only with Firefox
        for(i = 0; i < lightnings.length; i++){
            ctx.beginPath();
            for(u = 0; u < lightnings[i].length; u++){
                if(newRadius > 0 && lightnings[i].length > 0){
                    var x = canvas.width / img.width * lightnings[i][u]['X'];
                    var y = canvas.height / img.height * lightnings[i][u]['Y'];
                    ctx.moveTo(x+newRadius,y);
                    ctx.arc(x, y, newRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
                }
            }
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(" + colorArr[i] + ")";
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + colorArr[i] + ", 0.2)";
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }

    if(selectionRadius){ // Works with Chrome and Firefox
        if(mouseRadius > canvas.width / 100 * selectionRadius / 2) { mouseRadius = canvas.width / 100 * selectionRadius / 2; }

        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.moveTo(selectionX,selectionY);
        ctx.lineTo(selectionX-4,selectionY);
        ctx.moveTo(selectionX,selectionY);
        ctx.lineTo(selectionX,selectionY-4);
        ctx.moveTo(selectionX,selectionY);
        ctx.lineTo(selectionX+4,selectionY);
        ctx.moveTo(selectionX,selectionY);
        ctx.lineTo(selectionX,selectionY+4);

        ctx.moveTo((selectionX+mouseRadius),selectionY);
        ctx.arc(selectionX, selectionY, mouseRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgreen';
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    if(alert.length > 0) { // Works only with Firefox
        ctx.beginPath();
        for(i = 0; i < alert.length; i++){

            ctx.moveTo(alert[i][0],alert[i][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(alert[i][0]-5,alert[i][1]);
            ctx.moveTo(alert[i][0],alert[i][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(alert[i][0],alert[i][1]-5);
            ctx.moveTo(alert[i][0],alert[i][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(alert[i][0]+5,alert[i][1]);
            ctx.moveTo(alert[i][0],alert[i][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(alert[i][0],alert[i][1]+5);

            ctx.drawImage(alertImg, alert[i][0] - 12, alert[i][1]-24, 24, 24);
        }
        //ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        //ctx.stroke();
    }

    requestAnimFrame(function() {
        newLightningAnim();
    });
}

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();
```

I noticed that the only animation that is working doesn't contain any loops if that helps. I just simply have lack of skills with this...

Comment: I don't see the declaration of the `alert` variable. You also commented out the stroke - can you perhaps create a snippet that demonstrates your problem succinctly?

Comment: People should avoid using `alert` as a variable name: it is already a global function and is bound to cause problems.

Comment: Original code is much more longer, that's why you didn't see the declaration. The code also get's the lightning information dynamically and that's why I can't do snippet for it right now. I fully told what the problem is already.

Comment: @user3412847 Yeah, I know but my page don't use any original `alert` functions.

Comment: [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints) -> "Sample code and data": "That means if you want me to look at code, it should: **Be standalone**"

Comment: I have something library-type code for this. I rewrited the whole thing (Beta stage still) and for while it was working on Chome but then it happened again and only Firefox. It works on Firefox'es Android version too. The whole source is there: [Ukkotutka](http://ukkotutka.tk). The index.php generates the image for the .js script to draw and this takes about 2mins from the server so be patient and just wait. The code is a lot different and longer. All I know is that the problem is somewhere in the `lightningRadar.prototype.Animate()` function.